# javascript animation, a img move in the screen and every time when they touch the screen limit, they turn direction

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have been tried to made a code to move a image in the window, the img will keep moving to a same direction until it hits the screen limit, and them it will change the direct in order to keep  moving, The code i have been made is below:

```
var flySpeed = 5;
var maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
var maxHeight = window.innerHeight;
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition =0;
var xDirection = "right";
var yDirection = "down";



function movingBug()
{
    var bug = document.getElementById("bugImg");
    bug.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    bug.style.top = yPosition + "px";
    bug.style.position="absolute";

if (xDirection =="right")
    ++xPosition;
else if (xDirection =="left")
    ++xPosition;

if(yDirection =="down")
    ++yPosition;
else if (yDirection =="up")
    --yPosition;

 if(xPosition == screen.availWidth - 100)
 {
    xDirection ="left";
    yDirection = "down";

 }

if(xPosition == screen.availWidth - 10)
{
    xDirection = "right";
    yDirection = "up";

}

if(yPosition == screen.availHeight - 100)
{
    xDirection = "left";
    yDirection = "down";
}

if(yPosition == screen.availHeight - 10)
{
xDirection = "right";
yDirection = "up";
}


}
```

HTML part:

```
<body onload="setInterval('movingBug()',2);">
     <div id="bugImg"><img src = "Mosquito1.jpg" id ="bug1" width=100px; height=100px;></div>
</body>
```

Now, i think i need to use math random in order to let it move randomly, where should i add it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i just update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly using ++ instead of --

```
if (xDirection =="right")
    ++xPosition;
else if (xDirection =="left")
    --xPosition;//here
```

Also, you're missing:

```
if(yPosition == screen.availHeight - 10)
   {
    xDirection = "right";
    yDirection = "up";
   }
```

Comment: hey man i just update the question, i just want to let the img move in the screen and won't go out, what else do i need?

Comment: just update with my answer.

Comment: is still moving out, do i need change numbers?

Comment: may be, try changing...

Comment: hey man , do you know how to let it move randomly?